# Boundedness of a random function and of its derivatives.

Tags: probability-theory, functions, continuity, asymptotics

Let $f_n(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a sequence of real-valued functions, let $X_n$ be a random element of a Borel measurable space $(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathcal{X}_n)$ and let $(\Theta,d)$ a subset of an Euclidean space. Let me skim finer measurability assumptions, let's just assume that the random map $\theta \mapsto f_n(\theta,X_n)$ is continuously differentiable with probability 1 over an open ball $B_\epsilon:=\{
\theta \in \Theta: \, d(\theta,\theta_0)<\epsilon
\}$, for a fixed $\theta_0$ in the interior of $\Theta$.

**QUESTION 1**: can we conclude that $f_n(\theta_0,X_n)=O_p(1)$?

**QUESTION 2**: can we conclude that $ (\partial/\partial \theta_j)f_n(\theta,X_n)|_{\theta=\theta_0}=O_p(1)$, for $j\in \{1, \ldots, \text{dim}(\Theta)\}$?

My impression is that the answer is no. Under the assumptions, we only know that for every $n$ there exists a set $\Omega_n\in \mathcal{X}_n$ of probability 1 such that, for all $\omega \in \Omega_n$, $f_n(\theta, \omega)$ is continuously differentiable, thus Lipschitz on $\{
\theta \in \Theta: \, d(\theta,\theta_0)\leq \epsilon/2
\}$, which in turn implies there exists $M_\omega<\infty$ such that
$$
|f_n(\theta_0,\omega)|<M_\omega, \quad 
|(\partial/\partial \theta_j)f_n(\theta,\omega)|_{\theta=\theta_0} |<M_\omega, \, \forall j \in  \{1, \ldots, \text{dim}(\Theta)\}.
$$
However, this property holds $\omega$-wise inside a set $\Omega_n$ which varies with $n$. Thus, e.g., the random variables defined via
$$
Y_n(\omega)=\begin{cases}
M_\omega,
\quad \omega \in \Omega_n \\
0, \, \, \, \, \, \quad \omega \in \mathbb{X}_n \setminus \Omega_n
\end{cases}
$$
need not be $O_p(1)$. Is this reasoning correct?